# Implementing an observer class in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, observer-pattern

I am creating a bidding system where students can log in to a system and make a request for a tutor and sign a contract via a TKinter UI. I have managed to do this successfully. But now I am required to do the following,

"when a student or a tutor logs in into the system, the system should notify the user if there is a contract that is going to expire within a month."

I am having trouble trying to implement this feature as I feel this needs an observer and I for the life of me can't wrap my head around the Observer design pattern. I have no problem creating the  methods to call for the contracts and determine which contract expires but I can't seem to figure out how to like display it using an observer. Can I get some guidance on this?

For reference, this is the method that would get all the contracts that are expiring within a month.

```
    def expiring_contracts(self,username):
    user_contracts = self.all_contracts_by_user(username)
    expiring_contracts = []
    for i in user_contracts:
        time_string = i["expiryDate"]
        time_datetime = datetime.strptime(time_string,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
        one_month = datetime.now() + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
        if time_datetime < one_month:
            expiring_contracts.append(i)
    return expiring_contracts
```

the self.all_contracts_by_user is another method within this class that gets all the contracts by this user. I must implement a design pattern for this.

Comment: Why would you need an observer? This is a static check on login. Check all courses of just logging in user if one expires - if so: show popup...

Comment: I'm only doing it cause the assignment requires that I implement at least one Design pattern to my assignment. I have spent quite a bit of time thinking which design patterns I could implement in the assignment and I'm complete lost so I decided Observer would probably make the most sense.